# T-SQL query to locate next and previous record of a value

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am looking to check for the closest set of coordinates based on both coordinates, against any set of coordinates in the table.

I have a table with 5 columns of data. `colB` and `colC` have non sequential values.

```
colB             colC

12.54         -87.36
41.25          68.56
55.98         -82.45
40.12          78.52
```

`colA` is the primary key

I need to pass in two values to a query, like 40.81 for `colB` value and 75.56 for `colC` value.

Then determine the closest record between the difference of the four values. In this example, the difference between rec 2 and 4 for `colB` would be checked against the passed in value 40.81. Hence, 41.25 - 40.81 = .44 and 40.81 - 40.12 = .69 So in this instance, record 2 is closer and I would need to return all of the fields for record 2.

If someone could help get me close to solving this T-SQL query, I think I can complete the next part of the requirement which repeats the process for the `colC` value.

Comment: How did you arbitrarily choose records 2 and 4 for comparison? And what happened to the "75.56 for `colC` value"? I think this may not be a coherent problem...

Comment: @jmh_gr my understanding is that all records would be compared, but 2 and 4 were shown above as examples, chosen because one's just above the given value and one just below, so illustrating that the absolute value of the difference is what's important.  Col C should be included in the answer - it wasn't included above example to keep things simple.

Comment: @jmh_gr the records are the values each side of the passed in value. Correct colC was not include to simplify post.

Comment: You could probably use the formula of the distance between two points: `((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)^(0.5)`.

Comment: The problem is finding which set of points to check.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this - but I get result 4 as the closest:

```
declare @example table 
(
    colA bigint not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
    , colB numeric(18,9)
    , colC numeric(18,9)
)

insert @example select 12.54, -87.36
insert @example select 41.25,  68.56
insert @example select 55.98, -82.45
insert @example select 40.12,  78.52

declare @B numeric(18,9) =  40.81 
, @C numeric(18,9) = 75.56

select top 1 *
from @example
order by power(@B - colB, 2) + power(@C - colC, 2)
```

**Alternative**
The above gives you the record with the smallest difference in B and C.  If you want the smallest difference in B or C use the below:

```
select top 1 *
from @example
order by 
    case 
        when abs(@B - colB) < abs(@C - colC) 
            then abs(@B - colB) 
        else 
            abs(@C - colC) 
    end
```

Comment: ps. my reason for squaring the results instead of just using ABS is I figured this gives a Pythagorean take on the results; i.e. if you assumed B and C were sides of a right angled triangle they're ordered by the length of the hypotenuse.  However you can tweak as you wish.

Comment: John, thank you for this great example I will try to implement this and post back.

Comment: No worries - ps I realised I'd over complicated things by having the sub query return an ID then the outer query get the other columns for that ID - now it just returns the whole record at once.

Comment: Hey @marc11h; the negative won't effect it as I'm squaring the results.  I realised moments after posting that the reason I got 4 instead of 2 was down to the example only looking at B whilst mine looks at B and C - so this is correct.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I guess its late today. totally missed it.

Comment: I think 4 is still the incorrect record. The diffence in values for colB are both decimals. The difference of values for colC are both whole numbers

Comment: @marc11h Ah, I'd interpreted your question as the smallest difference in both columns - you were after the smallest in either - please see alternative answer above.

Comment: @JognLBevan I have run extensive testing on this routine and am not able to return the correct results, except when the routine is run strictly by SQL. I need to pass the values back to VB.net. Which is working, but never the correct results. I do get the correct results when I run the query in SSMS. I am calling the stored procedure, but it does not return the correct record.

Comment: Hey @Marc11h - to confirm what happens when you run the stored proc from SSMS; does that also work?  If not check the code in the stored proc is exactly the same as the code when run directly in SSMS.  If the stored proc works in SSMS but not when called from VB.Net, please can you post your VB code up (probably best to do it as another question but reference/link to this one in the description) and we'll try to spot what's going wrong.  Cheers, JB

Comment: Hey John, the SP run in SSMS returns same incorrect results as when called from VB. I only changed var defs to     '@'lat numeric (9,6),  '@'lon numeric (9,6), and now call directly to the table instead of building the table on the fly...select top 1 *
from [places]
order by 
    case

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a datatype of float for your columns.  What you're looking for is the lowest absolute value of the difference between your passed in value and the colB value.  Here's my simple solution that may not be the most performant:

```
DECLARE @value float = 40.81;

SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM MyTable m
ORDER BY ABS(colB-@value);
```

Comment: Perhaps, there should be a secondary order by something like `ColA` (for the lack of a better choice).

Comment: @AndriyM That's a good thought to add a tiebreaker column, but I assume that the OP will use the colC comparison for that purpose?

Comment: @Forester93 yes the values are floats.